# How to record multiple RTMP streams into multiple files with FFmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, multiple-instances

I tried the following, but it does not work.

```
ffmpeg -i rtmp://83.229.210.89/RAZTV/BTVraztv1 -map 0 -b:v 900k -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac -b:a 256k -strict -2 -t 3600 /media/TV_1T_3T_6/ffmpegtest/ort.mp4 -i rtmp://mirtv.cdnvideo.ru/mirtv-live/mirtv600.sdp -map 1 -b:v 900k -vcodec libx4 -acodec aac -b:a 256k -strict -2 -t 3600 /media/TV_1T_3T_6/ffmpegtest/mir.mp4 -i rtmp://chanson.cdnvideo.ru/chanson-live/shansontv.sdp -map 2 -b:v 900k -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac -b:a 256k -strict -2 -t 3600 /media/TV_1T_3T_6/ffmpegtest/shansontv.mp4 -i rtmp://83.229.210.89:1935/TROTV/BTVtro0 -map 3 -b:v 900k -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac -b:a 256k -strict -2 -t 3600 /media/TV_1T_3T_6/ffmpegtest/tro.mp4
```

Looks like it hangs on a second stream and no movement. S.O.S. Please help.
I have 4 stream URLs. I want them to be recording together at the same time.

With one ffmpeg command:

- I want: `rtmp://83.229.210.89/RAZTV/BTVraztv1 to record into file: /media/TV_1T_3T_6/ffmpegtest/ort.mp4`
- I want: `rtmp://mirtv.cdnvideo.ru/mirtv-live/mirtv600.sdp to record into file: /media/TV_1T_3T_6/ffmpegtest/mir.mp4`
- I want: `rtmp://chanson.cdnvideo.ru/chanson-live/shansontv.sdp to record into file: /media/TV_1T_3T_6/ffmpegtest/shansontv.mp4`
- I want: `rtmp://83.229.210.89:1935/TROTV/BTVtro0  to record into file: /media/TV_1T_3T_6/ffmpegtest/tro.mp4`

The log that I get right now is:

```
ffmpeg version 2.2.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jul  6 2014 21:42:17 with gcc 4.6 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-nonfree --enable-postproc --enable-libfaac --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-x11grab --enable-libvpx --enable-libmp3lame
  libavutil      52. 66.100 / 52. 66.100
  libavcodec     55. 52.102 / 55. 52.102
  libavformat    55. 33.100 / 55. 33.100
  libavdevice    55. 10.100 / 55. 10.100
  libavfilter     4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
  libswscale      2.  5.102 /  2.  5.102
  libswresample   0. 18.100 /  0. 18.100
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
[flv @ 0x24981c0] Stream discovered after head already parsed
Input #0, flv, from 'rtmp://83.229.210.89/RAZTV/BTVraztv1':
  Metadata:
    Server          : NGINX RTMP (github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module)
    displayWidth    : 720
    displayHeight   : 576
    fps             : 25
    profile         : 
    level           : 
  Duration: 00:00:00.00, start: 1826.816000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p, 720x576 [SAR 64:45 DAR 16:9], 699 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
    Stream #0:2: Data: none
[flv @ 0x261c7e0] Stream discovered after head already parsed
[flv @ 0x261c7e0] negative cts, previous timestamps might be wrong
    Last message repeated 8 times
Input #1, flv, from 'rtmp://mirtv.cdnvideo.ru/mirtv-live/mirtv600.sdp':
  Metadata:
    author          : 
    copyright       : 
    description     : 
    keywords        : 
    rating          : 
    title           : 
    presetname      : Custom
    creationdate    : Fri Jul 11 03:34:37 2014
                    : 
    videodevice     : AVerMedia Hybrid TV Video Capture
    avclevel        : 30
    avcprofile      : 66
    videokeyframe_frequency: 5
    audiodevice     : ?8=. 2E>4 (#AB@>9AB2> A ?>445@6
    audiochannels   : 1
    audioinputvolume: 100
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1038 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Video: h264 (Baseline), yuv420p(tv), 720x576 [SAR 1:1 DAR 5:4], 972 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #1:1: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, mono, s16p, 65 kb/s
    Stream #1:2: Data: none
```

Comment: Have you tried just running ffmpeg 4 different times ?

Comment: I did, for some reason only 2 would start recording. But separately all stream are working and recording fine. But I am starting recordings from within Java using:
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(recordCommand);

Answer (score 0):

WhooHooo, I understood the problem! So this is the fix. In my case FFMPEG was hanging on one of the problematic streams and thus wasn’t going forward to start recordings of the rest of the streams in the list. Basically with FFMPEG you have to execute command for each stream in a separate thread. Basically setup main method in your jar to start separate threads that would then start recording for each stream separately. This way if ffmpeg can’t connect to one of them and hangs, it won’t interrupt the recording of the rest of the streams.

```
package igor.recorder.ffmpeg;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class RecordRazTV extends Thread {

    String streamUrl="rtmp://83.229.210.89/RAZTV/BTVraztv1";
    String recordingPath="/media/TV_580_3T_9/raztv";
    String recordCommand = "";
    String streamAliasFileName="";

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Igors Log >> Inside the thread!");
        streamAliasFileName = recordingPath.substring(recordingPath.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
        recordCommand = "ffmpeg -i " + streamUrl + " -b:v 900k -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac -b:a 256k -strict -2 -t 3600 /media/TV_1T_3T_6/ffmpegtest/raztv.mp4";
        Process p;
        try {
            System.out.println("Igors Log >> Executing Runtime for FFMPEG: " + recordCommand);
            p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(recordCommand);
            System.out.println("Igors Log >> Done executing Runtime for FFMPEG");
            InputStream in = p.getErrorStream();
            int c;
            while ((c = in.read()) != -1)
            {
                System.out.print((char)c);
            }
            in.close();
            interrupt();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

http://www.russiangoogletv.com